# Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPRibbon not Working In Sharepoint SandBox Solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, ribbon-control

I wanna create Contextual Tab using Webpart In Sandbox Solution..that time I am getting Error as below When i am added Custom-Webpart :

Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.

In My Webpart's Code

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page).MakeTabAvailable("MyProject.Ribbon.HelloTab");
```

Is there another way to Solution To create Custom Ribbon Tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altering the ribbon is not permitted from within the sandbox. You have to options available to you.

1. Make your solution a farm solution (thereby giving it the necessary permissions)
2. Use a sandbox proxy the perform the steps on the ribbon (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798427.aspx))